# Magento query __toString() like Zend

Tags: magento

i can return this like a string?
Similar Zend Framework ->__toString()

here i select my categories (just name) when is active...

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

i want see that like string sql query "SELECT * ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(string)$categories->getSelect();`

You have to use the `getSelect()` function and cast the results of that to a string. It will make use of the aforementioned `__toString()` function and return the results of the query.